# How do I Make a txt file with all the 90 values of the same variables in python

Tags: python, loops, file-handling

The variable Numbers will have 90 randomly generated numbers.. How do I make a .txt file with all of the values of the variable. I tried the following code but it only saves one value of the variable in the file

```
import random


for i in range (90):
    Numbers = random.randrange(1,91)
    numberString = str(Numbers)

NumberFile = open('Numberfile.txt','w')
NumberFile.write(numberString) 
NumberFile.close()
```

Comment: Do you want to write numbers one after another without any delimiter?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `with open`

```
import random

with open('Numberfile.txt','w') as f:
    for i in range(90):
        num = random.randrange(1,91)
        f.write(str(num))
```

Answer (score 2):

- You are overwriting Number variable every time in for loop.
- You need to store numbers into list first then join and write to file.
- You can use any delimiter in `''.join()`.

```py
import random
Numbers = []
for i in range (90):
    Numbers.append(random.randrange(1,91))
numberString = '\n'.join(map(str,Numbers)) # empty delimetor can be replaced with , or new line (\n)

with open('Numberfile.txt','w') as f:
    f.write(numberString)
```

Comment: @Saturn Updated the answer to add new line delimetor so numbers comes in new line.